# C# Linq is removing a value from my entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

So, in a desperate attempt to wrangle EntityFramework into being usable. I am here..

```
private MyEntity Update(MyEntity orig) 
{
    //need a fresh copy so we can attach without adding timestamps
    //to every table....
    MyEntity ent;
    using (var db = new DataContext()) 
    {
        ent = db.MyEntities.Single(x => x.Id == orig.Id);
    }

    //fill a new one with the values of the one we want to save
    var cpy = new Payment()
    {
        //pk
        ID = orig.ID,
        //foerign key
        MethodId = orig.MethodId,
        //other fields
        Information = orig.Information,
        Amount = orig.Amount,
        Approved = orig.Approved,
        AwardedPoints = orig.AwardedPoints,
        DateReceived = orig.DateReceived
    };
    //attach it
    _ctx.MyEntities.Attach(cpy, ent);

    //submit the changes
    _ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

_ctx is an instance variable for the repository this method is in.

The problem is that when I call SubmitChanges, the value of MethodId in the newly attached copy is sent to the server as 0, when it is in fact not zero if I print it out after the attach but before the submit. I am almost certain that is related to the fact that the field is a foreign key, but I still do not see why Linq would arbitrarily set it to zero when it has a valid value that meets the requirements of the constraint on the foreign key.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what entity framework version r u using?

Comment: Calling `SaveChanges` directly after `Attach` does nothing. `Attach` puts an entity into `Unchanged` state. If you don't change the entity anymore after attaching EF doesn't send any command to the DB at all. And what is the purpose of this `ent` thing? And what is `o` which you pass into `Attach`? And what does your `Attach` do? The `Attach` of EF doesn't have two parameters. Is `SubmitChanges` only a call to `SaveChanges` or does it more?

Comment: Can you show the code inside of `_ctx.MyEntities.Attach(..., ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set `Method = orig.Method`, but I can't see your dbml, of course.

Comment: If I attach the reference, it will attempt to insert that entity on submit changes, obviously this causes a pk issue on the Method table

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to attach the foreign key reference

```
var cpy = new Payment()
{
    //pk
    ID = orig.ID,
    //other fields
    Information = orig.Information,
    Amount = orig.Amount,
    Approved = orig.Approved,
    AwardedPoints = orig.AwardedPoints,
    DateReceived = orig.DateReceived
};

//create stub entity for the Method and Add it.
var method = new Method{MethodId=orig.MethodId)
_ctx.AttachTo("Methods", method);
cpy.Methods.Add(method);

//attach it
_ctx.MyEntities.Attach(cpy, o);

//submit the changes
_ctx.SubmitChanges();
```